# Gradle: Could not find property 'installDist' on task ':stage'

Tags: gradle

I have a build.gradle in my root project which looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        //....etc
    }
}

mainClassName = "com.website.Main"
task stage {
    dependsOn installDist
    println "Running Stage"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.7' //version required
}
```

However when I run `gradle stage` I get:

```
* What went wrong:          
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'root-module'.
> Could not find property 'installDist' on task ':stage'.
```

The weird thing is if I run `.\gradlew stage` it works fine... Why is this?

Comment: Problem solved: It was a version issue...

Comment: Can you please eloborate? I'm experiencing the same issue/

Comment: @Simon i was running 'gradle stage' rather than ./gradlew stage' (whch i meant to use). Basically the version of gradle i had on my pc was old and didnt have the installDist task. The local gradle wrapper distribution i had was more recent though (v2.7) hence why that worked. Try upgrading your gradle version :)

Comment: I had to add the 'distribution' plugin to build.gradle. See details here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html